# Android Bitmap.Compress saves image of Low Quality and Scaled down image

Tags: android, android-studio, bitmap, android-bitmap

I am trying to make an app that takes a picture and embed another image like a logo onto the original image. But I have a problem in the initial stages.

I am trying to save the image from the Bitmap received from onActivityResult for the camera intent. But after using the following code, the images are scaled-down and compressed too much and looks bad. Can someone help me retain the picture quality and size?

Here are the pictures that the app saved:

[image] [image]

```java
   public void saveBitmapToGallery(Bitmap bm,String picturename){
        String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
        File mydir = new File(picturepath);
        DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
        displayheight = dm.heightPixels;
        displaywidth = dm.widthPixels;
        File file = new File(mydir, picturename+".JPG");
        try {
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
            bm.createScaledBitmap(bm,displaywidth,displayheight,true);
            bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,100, fos);
            fos.flush();
            fos.close();
        }catch (FileNotFoundException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

I expect an image like the general camera app so that I can work on embedding the logo once I can get my app to save good quality images.

Answer (score 0):

the image did not convert into byte output

also, Go for My Github Profile for this
https://github.com/axarlotwala/CafeDelear`enter code here`

// using intent open file chooser option

```
private void ShowFileChooser() {

    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Select Picture"),PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);

}
```

// show selected and path image in imageview

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    PATH = data.getData();

    try {
        bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getActivity().getContentResolver(),PATH);
        cat_image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        tv_path.setText("Path : " .concat(GetPath(PATH)));


    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

//get correct path of image
private String GetPath(Uri uri){

    String result;
    Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(uri,null,null,null,null);
    if (cursor == null){
        result = uri.getPath();
    }else {

        cursor.moveToFirst();
        int id = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        result = cursor.getString(id);
        cursor.close();
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Hi axar, Thank you for your help. But I don't understand why did you mention about the path? I get the picture from the camera intent and I have the Bitmap for the image I need to save, But when I used the code I mentioned to save, the images are scaled down too much and have a tiny picture. I hope you understood my issue.

Comment: the path is to cross-check your selected image is correct or not so ..for AlterNet testing purpose I have used it

Answer (score 0):

Well, I figured out what was wrong with the output image. We need to use EXTRA_OUTPUT for the picture to be saved in full size, otherwise only a thumbnail is saved.

Here is what we need to to before starting camera activity for result

```
if (picturefile != null) {
                Uri pictureUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, getApplicationContext().getPackageName() +
                        ".provider", picturefile);
                imageIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, pictureUri); //This makes the image to save in full rather than just a low quality scaled-down thumbnail.
            }

            startActivityForResult(imageIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
```